# USB port sniffing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb

I am working on a project now and I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. I need to do some sniffing on a USB device, and I used to do it with usbmon. However, usbmon doesn't seem to be available on Ubuntu 14.

Is there a way to get usbmon as a module? If not, is there a tool I can use to sniff ports?

Answer (score 0):

usbmon is located in the extras (linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic) packages.

You can locate files in packages using:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=usbmon)